# Upload metadata to a folder with power apps

Tags: document-library, flow, powerapp, metadata, app

I.have a document library named Project, with metadata STATUS, PROGRAM, BUILDING and Projectleader.

I have a APP with flow, thats create a documentfolder. But I also want to set the above metadata in the same APP.

When using update file properties, I see the metadata, but its wants an integer input.

I defined the metadata in the APP with texinput and used power apps V2 in the flow.

Who has a solution?

Comment: Try using `int()` function in flow to convert number string to actual number. example: `int('10')`

Comment: Thanks wil try it.

Comment: Let me know if it works. You have to add it using "Dynamic Content" > "Expression"

Comment: I used the custom entry, but it dont accept the expression.

Comment: Can you share the expression you used with screenshots if possible? Maybe you are using wrong expression syntax.

Comment: Is this working for you now?